# Can you move the Excel Ribbon?

Tags: excel, ms-word, excel-2010, powerpoint-2010

When I am working on my work laptop, I try to maximize my 14" screen space. I experimented with hiding the Ribbon so that it only appears when you move the mouse to the top of the screen, but what I would really like is to move the Ribbon so that I can locate it vertically on either the left or the right of the screen, similarly like what you can do with the Windows taskbar.

Is there a way to do this in Microsoft Office, or is hiding the Ribbon the only option?

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  The ribbon stays where it is.  Period.